# Low volume in Chromecast videostream

Tags: chromecast, volume

Im struggling for a while now but i am unable to find a solution.
While streaming video to my Chromecast (Netflix, Disney, Prime) the volume is extremely low. The weird thing is that streaming audio (Spotify) goed well.

Therefor i dont think its related to the tv itself but more how the video stream is handled.

I have tried a lot, ensured that the connections are ok, factory resets and such but till now not much success.

Hope that someone has a clue since it is quiet anoying

Pim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggles and multiple contact moments with Google support the only option they came with was a fresh install of the device.

The actual problem lies that there is some sort of hidden volume slider that i can only adjust via my Google Assistant. When i say to another device to put my volume to 100% suddenly my volume went up